# Date field issue if IE browser is zoomed to 150% and 175%

Tags: css, internet-explorer, zooming

If I load the IE browser and zoom is 150% and 175%, it will display the Date field as broken. If I load it 125% and below or 200%, it is as expected. For other browsers it is working fine. Anyone who can recommend fix for this?

[image: 1]

Normal:
[image: 2]

Comment: I make [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/yuzhou0602/012xovde/1/) like yours and it can zoom well in IE 11: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqDnf.png. Maybe your code is not like mine. Only the images is not enough. So could you please provide [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? So that we can reproduce the issue on our sides and see how to help.

Answer (score 0):

Define the `width` of its parent div in which these 3 `inputs` are like

```
.parent{
   width: 300px;
}
```